# What were Felicity and Ray saying about Supergirl?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, crossovers

In the crossover of Legends, Flash, Arrow and Supergirl, near the end there is a conversation that bewildered me between Felicity and Ray.

Felicity looks at Supergirl and says something like "It's like looking in the mirror". And Ray answered something like "I think she looks like my cousin".

This seems to lampshade and make fun of the fact that Felicity and Supergirl are played by the same actor and also Ray and Superman (in Supergirl) are played by the same actor. But AFAIK this is not true. There are in both cases different actors.

So what does this conversation mean or refer to?

Comment: While I was able to answer my own question, I feel that the question title and tags can be improved to make it better to find by people who have the same question.

Comment: "This seems to lampshade and make fun of the fact that Felicity and Supergirl are played by the same actor" - Wait, what?  [Emily Bett Rickards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emily_Bett_Rickards) and [Melissa Benoist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melissa_Benoist) aren't the same person...

Comment: Thats what I write one line later. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the edits

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it myself:

[Legends of Tomorrow' Made the Superman Joke Fans Waited For](https://www.inverse.com/article/24624-legends-of-tomorrow-dc-superman-returns-brandon-routh)

> Ten years after becoming the Man of Steel in Bryan Singer’s Superman Returns, Brandon Routh is playing another DC superhero, the Atom, on DC’s Legends of Tomorrow. In this week’s blockbuster crossover “Invasion!” that includes Supergirl starring Melissa Benoist, Routh’s history as a Kryptonian was brought up — but it was purely for laughs.
>
> After the Dominators were pushed back into a retreat, the team celebrates with a private party in their makeshift HQ. Ray Palmer (Routh), Felicity (Emily Bett Rickards), and Kara Zor-El (Benoist) have an off-screen conversation before Kara walks away. Felicity jokes that Kara is “like looking into a mirror” (Long blonde hair? Thick black glasses? Nerd-chic wardrobe? Sure, it checks out.) while Ray has a more interesting revelation.
>
> “Yeah, you know what’s funny? She really kinda looks like my cousin.” Ray blinks. Felicity stares. Marc Guggenheim snorts. And fans everywhere love it. (The joke depends on audiences knowing Supergirl is Superman’s cousin, which is probably a no-brainer to anyone tuned in to a crossover event.)